Excel VBA macro enters an infinite loop - unable to find a fix
I'm trying to create a spreadsheet where a user locates the correct "Arrival" or "Departure" cell associated with their name, enters a space (or other character), hits return and the current time (or time/date) is entered into the cell. The following is the simple spreadsheet.
Excel Attendance Record

I created a Change Event macro so that when the user has selected the correct cell and made a change (eg pressing the space bar) then return or any arrow key, the macro fires up. The macro is:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C4:C11")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
    Target.Value = Now
End If
End Sub


The result is that the current time/date is entered into the cell that was selected however, putting the time/date into the cell creates a change event and the macro enters an infinite loop.
How do I stop the macro from entering this infinite loop - or is there a better way to achieve the desired result?
Can anyone suggest a solution?

Put a statement Application.EnableEvents = False before you write into the cell and Application.EnableEvents = True when your done.

Add Application.EnableEvents = False at the start of the procedure so the event doesn't run again.  Remember to turn it back to True at the end of the procedure.
Also Ctrl+Shift+; will enter the current time to a cell so maybe use that rather than a procedure to do it?

@DarrenBartrup-Cook Or, use the "Before Double-Click" event to control it with the mouse instead of the "Change" event, or check that the current value is only a single character long before changing anything, etc…

A Worksheet BeforeDoubleClick: Add TimeStamp
Simple

As suggested by Chronocidal in your comments, using the Worksheet BeforeDoubleClick event is more suitable in your case.

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const TARGET_RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "C4:D11"
    Dim TargetValue As Variant: TargetValue = Now
    
    ' Exit if no cell of the target range was double-clicked.
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range(TARGET_RANGE_ADDRESS)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Exit edit mode.
    Cancel = True
    
    ' Write target value.
    Target.Value = TargetValue
    
End Sub

Disable Events

If you want to disable events e.g. prevent triggering the Worksheet Change event or whatnot, you could use the following.
The complications are probably overkill for this event but may come in handy when dealing with the Worksheet Change event.

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const TARGET_RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "C4:D11"
    Dim TargetValue As Variant: TargetValue = Now
    Const DISABLE_EVENTS As Boolean = True
    
    ' Exit if no cell of the target range was double-clicked.
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range(TARGET_RANGE_ADDRESS)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Exit edit mode.
    Cancel = True
    
    ' Write target value.
    If DISABLE_EVENTS Then
        WriteValueNoEvents Target, TargetValue
    Else
        Target.Value = TargetValue
    End If
    
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Disables events before writing a single value to each cell
'               of a range (in one go) and reenabling events.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub WriteValueNoEvents( _
        ByVal rg As Range, _
        ByVal Value As Variant)
    Dim ErrorMessage As String, WasErrorRaised As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' start error-handling routine
        
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    rg.Value = Value
    
ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next ' defer error trapping to prevent endless loop
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        If WasErrorRaised Then MsgBox ErrorMessage, vbCritical
    On Error GoTo 0 ' turn on error trapping
    Exit Sub
ClearError: ' continue error-handling routine
    ErrorMessage = "Run-time error [" & Err.Number & "]:" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description
    WasErrorRaised = True
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

